# heap overflow affecting other programs

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I was trying to create the condition for malloc to return a NULL pointer. In the below program, though I can see malloc returning NULL, once the program is forcebly terminated, I see that all other programs are becoming slow and finally I had to reboot the system. So my question is whether the memory for heap is shared with other programs? If not, other programs should not have affected. Is OS is not allocating certain amount of memory at the time of execution? I am using windows 10, Mingw.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void mallocInFunction(void)
{
    int *ptr=malloc(500);
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Could not be allocated\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Allocated memory successfully\n");
    }
}


int main (void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        mallocInFunction();
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `void *mallocInFunction(void) { void *ptr = malloc (500); ... return ptr; }` to allow you to gauge success or failure of the allocation. Then `while (mallocInFunction()) {}` in `main`. Your memory is shared (not exactly as *virtual* memory is allocated to each executable), and when you begin running out, your system should shut down non-essential processes.

Comment: The program requests heap size increase when needed and the OS supplies more memory ... then other programs slow down because the OS ends up using disk swap space to supply other programs because your program used all the real memory. (Very roughly speaking)

Comment: Other programs might become slow for sometime but soon *should* recover to normal operation when their pages are swapped in. If your swap is less the OS also might have to kill some processes which it would later have to start again. If your machine is completely unusable after such an experiment, you might want to try increasing swap space (it is called Virtual Memory in windows) before the experiment. Usual swap size is equal to Physical memory size.

Comment: @M.M. In this case the issue is probably the swap getting filled up too because the malloc is going to return NULL only after the swap is also full.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I think Windows usually doesn't return NULL, it just lazy allocates and then kills processes if swap fills up

Comment: @Ôrel AFAIK `ulimit` is on *NIX systems. The OP here is using MinGW on Windows.

Comment: @M.M Yes agreed. Explains why other processes are suffering badly too. Many services must be getting killed. But OP mentions that he gets NULL and then had to forcibly terminate. Maybe he is running in debug mode or something where the windows allocator also clears the pages on MEM_COMMIT. If the swap is full too, the commit operation would fail and I think the malloc would then return NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is whether the memory for heap is shared with other programs?

Physical memory (RAM) is a resource that is shared by all processes. The operating system makes decisions about how much RAM to allocate to each process and adjusts that over time.

> If not, other programs should not have affected. Is OS is not allocating certain amount of memory at the time of execution?

At the time the program starts executing, the operating system has no idea how much memory the program will want or need. Instead, it deals with allocations as they happen. Unless configured otherwise, it will typically do everything it possibly can to allow the program's allocation to succeed because presumably there's a reason the program is doing what it's doing and the operating system won't try to second guess it.

Answer (score 3):

> ... whether the memory for heap is shared with other programs?

Well, the C standard doesn't exactly require a *heap*, but in the context of a task-switching, multi-user and multi-threaded OS, *of course* memory is shared between processes! The C standard doesn't require *any* of this, but this is all pretty common stuff:

- CPU cache memory tends to be preferred for code that's executed *often*, though this might get swapped around quite a bit; that may or may not be swapped to a *heap*.
- Task switching causes registers to be swapped to other forms of memory; that may or may not be swapped to a *heap*.
- Entire pages are swapped to and from disk, so that other programs can make use of them when your OS switches execution away from your program and to the other programs, and when it's your programs turn to execute again *among other reasons*. This may or may not involve manipulating the *heap*.

FWIW, you're referring to memory that has [allocated storage duration](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4). It's best to avoid using terms like *heap* and *stack*, as they're virtually meaningless. The memory you're referring to is on a *silicon chip*, regardless of whether it uses a *heap* or a *stack*.

> ... Is OS is not allocating certain amount of memory at the time of execution?

Speaking of silicon chips and execution, your OS likely only has control of *one* processor (a silicon chip which contains some logic circuits and memory, among other things I'm sure) with which to execute *many* programs! To summarise this post, **yes, your program is most likely *sharing those silicon chips* with other programs!**

On a tangential note, I don't think *[heap overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_overflow)* means what you think it means.

Answer (score 1):

Your question cannot be answered in the context of C, the language. For C, there's no such thing as a *heap*, a *process*, ...

But it can be answered in the context of *operating systems*. Even a bit generically because many modern multitasking OSes do similar things.

Given a modern multitasking OS, it will use *virtual address spaces* for each process. The OS manages a fixed size of physical RAM and divides this into pages, when a process needs memory, such pages are *mapped* into the process' virtual address space (typically using a different virtual address than the physical one). So when all memory pages are claimed by the OS itself and by the processes running, the OS will typically save some of these pages that are not in active use to disk, in a *swap area*, in order to serve this page as a fresh page to the next process requesting one. But when the original page **is** touched (and this is typically the case with `free()`, see below), it must first be loaded from disk again, but to have a free page for this, *another* page must be saved to swap space.

This is, like all disk I/O, slow, and it's probably what you see happening here.

Now to fully understand this: what does `malloc()` do? It typically requests from the operating system to have the memory of the own process increased (and if necessary, the OS does this by mapping another page), and it uses this new memory by writing some information there about the block of memory requested (so `free()` can work correctly later) and ultimately returns a pointer to a block that's free to use for the program. `free()` uses the information written by `malloc()`, modifies it to indicate this block is free again, and it typically **can't give any memory back to the OS** because there are other `malloc()`d blocks in the same page. It will give memory back when possible, but that's the exception in a typical scenario where dynamic allocations are heavily used.

So, the answer to your question is: Yes, the RAM is shared because there is only one set of physical RAM. The OS does the best it can to hide that fact and *virtualize* RAM, but if a process consumes all that is there, this will have visible effects.

Answer (score 1):

[malloc()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) is not system call but libc library function. So when a program ask for allocating memory via malloc(), system call brk()/sbrk() OR mmap() to allocated page(s), more details [here](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/Malloc_tutorial.pdf).

Please keep in mind that the memory you get is all virtual in nature, that means if you have 3GB of physical RAM you can actually allocate almost infinite memory. So how does this happens? This happens via concept called 'paging', where system stores and retrieves data from secondary memory storage(HDD/SDD) to main memory(RAM), more details [here](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=89).

So with this theory, out of memory usually quite rare but program like above which is checking system limits, this can happen. This is nicely explained [here](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html).

Now, why other programs are sort of hanged OR slow? Because they all share the same operating system and system is starving for resource. In fact at a point the system will crash and reboot again.

Hope this helps?

Comment: A linux OOM link for a Windows question? You might as well have used [this analogy](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/) ;)

Comment: My effort is to explain what happens under the hood, this is not writing on-the-stone but the chain of events (yes specific to Linux system). Example malloc() manages memory in variety of ways (best-fit, first-fit, last-fit, buddy, etc), which is implementation specific, but the protocol they all follow is same. Pease correct me if i am wrong :)